# Forçar a declaração de propriedades

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, propriedade, trait

Estou implementando uma funcionalidade de filtros em algumas classes de minha aplicação através de `traits`.

A função da `trait` recorrerá a variáveis da classe através de algumas propriedades definidas na classe:

```
<?php

trait FilterTrait {    
    public function scopeApplyFilters($filters) {
        foreach (self::$allowedFilters as $filter) {
             // Executa método
        }
     }
}

class EstoqueMeta extends Eloquent {
    use FilterTrait;
    static public $allowedFilters = array('foo','bar');
}
```

Gostaria de forçar a partir da `trait` que a propriedade seja definida na classe.
Pensei implementar essa funcionalidade a partir de herança, porém eu perderia a flexibilidade de uso da `trait` em outras partes da minha aplicação.

**Existe alguma forma de "forçar" a declaração das propriedades a partir da `trait`? Caso negativo, há alguma alternativa sem envolver herança?**

---

Meu problema não é declarar a propriedade na `trait`, inclusive foi essa minha primeira tentativa, mas caso a classe tenha a mesma propriedade, acontecerá um erro de colisão com o nome das propriedades.

```
trait FilterTrait {    
    public $allowedFilters = array();    
    public function scopeApplyFilters($filters) {
        foreach (self::$allowedFilters as $filter) {
             // Executa método
        }
     }
}

class EstoqueMeta {
    use FilterTrait;    
    public $allowedFilters = array('foo', 'bar');
}
```

> Fatal error:  EstoqueMeta and FilterTrait define the same property
>   ($allowedFilters) in the composition of EstoqueMeta. However, the
>   definition differs and is considered incompatible. Class was composed
>   in [...][...] on line 23

[**Exemplo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9f8649f894ac8708df7c1f43377189af49469a3f)

Comment: Declarar a propriedade na *trait* não resolve? Não conheço a implementação de *trait* no PHP, por que perderia a possibilidade de usar em outras classes?

Comment: @bigown ja tentei, mas o php não permite.

Comment: A propriedade precisa ser static? você pode declarar propriedades na Trait sem problema algum!

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1901/essa-pergunta-pode-ser-considerada-uma-pergunta-camale%C3%A3o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que não seja possível fazer o que você quer, propriedades são no máximo herdadas até onde eu sei. Mas é possível resolver isso sem a necessidade de definir uma propriedade, você pode deixar um método para sua classe implementar, podes utilizar uma interface ou deixar uma método abstrato na sua trait para fazer isso

Exemplo:

```php
    trait FilterTrait
    {

        abstract public function getAllowedFilters();

        public function scopeApplyFilters(array $filters)
        {
            foreach ($filters as $filter) {
                if (false === \in_array($filter, $this->getAllowedFilters())) {

                }
            }
        }

    }

    class EstoqueMeta
    {

        use FilterTrait;

        public function getAllowedFilters()
        {
            return array('foo', 'bar');
        }

    }

    $estoque = new EstoqueMeta();

    $estoque->scopeApplyFilters(array('foo'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Até o momento para forçar que a propriedade seja definida, implementei um método na `trait` que dispara uma `Exception` caso a propriedade não esteja definida.

```
trait FilterTrait {    
    public $allowedFilters = array();    
    public function scopeApplyFilters($filters) {

        $this->checkProperties();

        foreach (self::$allowedFilters as $filter) {
             // Executa método
        }
    }

    private function checkProperties(){
        if (!isset(self::$allowedFilters)){
            throw new Exception('Required properties are not defined.');
        }
    }

}

// Classe
class EstoqueMeta {
    use FilterTrait;          
}

$model = new EstoqueMeta();

// Exception: Required properties are not defined.
$model->scopeApplyFilters(['foo' => 123, 'bar' => 456]);
```

A desvantagem desse método é que caso a `trait` tenha mais métodos que precisem de propriedades fora do escopo dela, é preciso chamar o método `checkProperties()` em todos os métodos.